Securing AWS Cognito Signup Route
I've a ExpressJS application and I'm using AWS Cognito to provide simple signup capabilities to users.
Javascript SDK does not support a Client Secret according to docs.
My question is, how should I protect this signup route? If it is ever exposed to public, anyone can create unlimited users.
How will ClientID and Client Secret play a role in this? I'm having difficulty in understanding that procedure.
This is my code if anyone is wondering:
const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});

router.post("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, gender, birthdate, subject, password } = req.body;
  const command = new SignUpCommand({
    ClientId: process.env.ClientID ,
    Username: email,
    Password: password,
    UserAttributes: [
      { Name: "email", Value: email },
      { Name: "gender", Value: gender },
      { Name: "birthdate", Value: birthdate },
      { Name: "custom:subject", Value: subject },
    ],
  });
  try {
    const result = await client.send(command);
    return res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    return res;
  }
});

I'm thinking this: Even if there was a client secret, it will be present on my server side and already available on every API request. So how should I protect this so that only MY application (the frontend) is able to call this API?
CORS won't help for CURL or Postman requests.
